# Why does comparison of two integers of MAX_VALUE fail in java?

Tags: java

I have the following lines of code in Java:

```
public class myProjects {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Integer d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Integer e = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(e);
    if(d == e){
        System.out.println("They are equal\n");

    }else {
        System.out.println("They are not equal\n");
    }
}

}

Output:
2147483647
2147483647
They are not equal
```

Why are they not equal even though they have the same value?

Answer (score 3):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` returns an `int`. When doing `Integer d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` it boxes the `int` to an `Integer` via `Integer.valueOf`.

Since by default the cache is from [-128, 127] `valueOf` will return new instance for each call. Thus they are not the same references.

You can see this in the generated bytecode:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #3                  // int 2147483647
       2: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: astore_1
       6: ldc           #3                  // int 2147483647
       8: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

and the source code of `Integer.valueOf`:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Comment: This helps.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Objects, not primitives.

You should be using `d.equals(e);` instead of `d == e`

`d == e` evaluates whether or not the object is the same, and they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, `Integer` is an `Object` and not a `primitive` value,

to check for equality of objects, you need to use `equals` method

e.g.

```
if(d.equals(e)) {....}
```

Answer (score 0):

As sharonbn mentions in the comment.

Try changing

```
Integer d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Integer e = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

To

```
int d = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int e = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

and see what happens.